# Laravel Http client

Tags: laravel, api, http

Could someone help me regarding Laravel Http client. I have this endpoint
`http://projects.knmi.nl/klimatologie/uurgegevens/getdata_uur.cgi?stns=240&vars=RH&start=2020071500&end=2020072200` which store in `$result` variable. my problem is when I tried to dump (`$result->body()`) I don't know how to get the data excluding all the labels starting with `'#'`. Thanks

sample return data:

```
# BRON: KONINKLIJK NEDERLANDS METEOROLOGISCH INSTITUUT (KNMI)
# Opmerking: door stationsverplaatsingen en veranderingen in waarneemmethodieken zijn deze tijdreeksen van uurwaarden mogelijk inhomogeen! Dat betekent dat deze reeks van gemeten waarden niet geschikt is voor trendanalyse. Voor studies naar klimaatverandering verwijzen we naar de gehomogeniseerde reeks maandtemperaturen van De Bilt <http://www.knmi.nl/klimatologie/onderzoeksgegevens/homogeen_260/index.html> of de Centraal Nederland Temperatuur <http://www.knmi.nl/klimatologie/onderzoeksgegevens/CNT/>.
# 
# 
# STN      LON(east)   LAT(north)     ALT(m)  NAME
# 240:         4.790       52.318      -3.30  SCHIPHOL
# 
# YYYYMMDD = datum (YYYY=jaar,MM=maand,DD=dag); 
# HH       = tijd (HH=uur, UT.12 UT=13 MET, 14 MEZT. Uurvak 05 loopt van 04.00 UT tot 5.00 UT; 
# RH       = Uursom van de neerslag (in 0.1 mm) (-1 voor <0.05 mm); 
# 
# STN,YYYYMMDD,   HH,   RH
# 
  240,20200715,   24,    0
  240,20200716,   24,    0
  240,20200717,   24,    0
  240,20200718,   24,    0
  240,20200719,   24,    0
  240,20200720,   24,    0
  240,20200721,   24,    0
```

Codes

```
$result = Http::get('http://projects.knmi.nl/klimatologie/uurgegevens/getdata_uur.cgi?stns=240&vars=RH&start=2020071500&end=2020072200');
        dd($result->body());
```

Comment: Show us the code please, it's unclear what you have done and what is going wrong

Comment: Which labels do you mean? If the data comes as listed, why not simply remove the first line? Or parse the data using a CSV parser?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I've updated my question